# Error when inserting function mysql_real_escape_string in a string

Tags: php, mysql

I know we can insert a function between strings in Javascript, so it should be possible with PHP too.

Javascript:

```
var myString = "aString " + function_returning_string() + " anotherString";
```

PHP: it can be done with sprintf like the example on this page http://fr.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($user),
            mysql_real_escape_string($password));
```

It works great but I want to know why it doesn't work when we put everything in a string directly like that:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."' AND password='".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."'";
```

How can we do this?

After some answers I've realized that the problem has nothing to do with functions embedded in a string because other functions are working, so it is apparently the mysql_real_escape_string <strike>(deprecated)</strike> function.

This function doesn't work too when I save the result in a variable and then insert it into a string.

Here's my complete php file, no modifications with 500 Internal Server Error in Firebug console:

```
<?php
/*ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

require_once('/var/www/FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php');
ob_start();
$firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true);*/


$reference = $_POST['reference'];
$txtGauche = $_POST['motGauche'];
$txtDroite = $_POST['motDroite'];
$ptGauche = $_POST['repGauche'];
$ptDroite = $_POST['repDroite'];

$base = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");

$sql_utf8 = "SET NAMES utf8;";
$sql_base = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS elan
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;";
$sql_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS relier_points (
`Reference` VARCHAR(20),
`TexteGauche` VARCHAR(500),
`TexteDroite` VARCHAR(500),
`ReponseGauche` VARCHAR(300),
`ReponseDroite` VARCHAR(300));";

/*$sql_insert = sprintf("INSERT INTO relier_points VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",
    mysql_real_escape_string($reference),
    mysql_real_escape_string($txtGauche),
    mysql_real_escape_string($txtDroite),
    mysql_real_escape_string($ptGauche),
    mysql_real_escape_string($ptDroite));*/

$reference = mysql_real_escape_string($reference);
$txtGauche = mysql_real_escape_string($txtGauche);
$txtDroite = mysql_real_escape_string($txtDroite);
$ptGauche = mysql_real_escape_string($ptGauche);
$ptDroite = mysql_real_escape_string($ptDroite);

$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO relier_points VALUES('$reference','$txtGauche','$txtDroite','$ptGauche','$ptDroite')");


mysql_query($sql_utf8,$base);
mysql_query($sql_base,$base);

mysql_select_db("elan",$base);

mysql_query($sql_table,$base);
$result = mysql_query($sql_insert,$base);

//$firephp->log($result, 'test');

mysql_close($base);

if($result == TRUE)
    echo "Exercice $reference reçu";
else
    var_dump($result);
?>
```

Oh sorry, I was tired yesterday. In case you didn't noticed, I forgot removing the last ")" from sprintf when converting directly $sql_insert in a string.

By the way, it is now working without variables:

```
$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO relier_points VALUES('"
    .mysql_real_escape_string($reference)."','"
    .mysql_real_escape_string($txtGauche)."','"
    .mysql_real_escape_string($txtDroite)."','"
    .mysql_real_escape_string($ptGauche)."','"
    .mysql_real_escape_string($ptDroite)."')";
```

So this was a clumsy error but at least I've learned that I should use PDO or MySQLi instead of mysql_ functions :)

Comment: what error you got for 2nd example?

Comment: What happens when you do that? How does it differ from what you were hoping for? (When asking technical questions, "it doesn't work" is almost always the Wrong Thing to say. Be specific!)

Comment: The 2nd PHP example works fine for me.  http://codepad.org/NwEvj5Np

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: @Rocket You're right! I've just understand that the problem was not here with a standard function returning a string but with mysql_real_escape_string it doesn't work and this function is returning a string o_O
Look at kaan alves kilic post, it doesn't work too when using variables!

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan a nice 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is not deprecated. however, using it in the code directly is apparently a bad practice. Same goes for the mysqli though.

Comment: @YourCommonSense it's what people said me here, mysql_ functions will be deprecated and mysql_real_escape_string has already a replacement with mysqli http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php
I think you want to say procedural style is a bad practice, right?

Comment: no. procedural style is not bad. mysql_real_escape_string is not deprecated. people have no clue. mysqli_ version of this function shouldn't be used directly in the code as well as mysql_ one. one have to use it indirectly, as a part of query building facility. Otherwise it will allow an injection. PDO::quote() is much better because it does escape AND adding quotes.

Comment: @YourCommonSense thanks, and it's not "MySQL only"

Comment: @baptx but nothing forbids you to create your own function based on either mysql_real_escape_string() or mysqli_real_escape_string() that does both escaping and quoting. The only drawback of escaping - it us useless without surrounding quotes. As long as you are adding quotes around escaped value, you can use mysql_real_escape_string all right

Comment: @tereško Thanks for advice and tutorial, I'm using PDO prepared statement for my project.
No need for mysql_real_escape_string or PDO::quote, even for "'" character who was causing problems before with SQL INSERT :)

Answer (score -2):

You should try with veriables.I mean like this

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='$user' AND password='$passowrd'";
```

It should be work.And its easy to reading code and also simple.

Comment: My question was how to insert a function, not a variable, in a string.
But I've tried this solution before and curiously it doesn't work too :/